# Get users who have permissions on a particular list item

Tags: permissions, item-level-permissions, pnpjs

Is it possible to check the list of users who have read access on a particular item using PnP JS?

I tried something like this but `roleAssignments` is not available on item it seems.

```
const response = await sp.web.lists
  .getByTitle("MyList")
  .items.getById(1)
  .roleAssignments();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I missed out the imports.

```
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
import "@pnp/sp/security";
```